# What is this discoloured patch in my smoked prosciutto?

Tags: meat, italian-cuisine

I bought an Italian selection of cooked meats from a well-known British supermarket chain, which begins with T and rhymes with Fresco.

Within this selection is smoked prosciutto. However, it appears to contain discoloured patches which range from light brown to black, and I’m unsure as to whether to be concerned.

My initial thought was that it may be peppercorns but, on closer inspection, it doesn’t appear to be, and I’m unsure as to whether to return the product to the store.

[image: Discoloured patches within my smoked prosciutto]

Comment: No clue what that is, but perhaps you won't be dining *al tesco* tonight ;) Maybe try 'rhymes with Mazda', 'abbreviation of vivAldi', 'childish pronunciation of Little', or 'closest I can get is Gainsborough's'. Or, Wait, Rose, there's no Safe Way any more, only More Reasons… *[sometimes I can't resist the word-play jokes]*

Comment: You’ve got a good sense of humour, I’ll give you that much for sure!

Comment: that looks gross...

Comment: That doesn't look good to me. I'm a little surprised that its "smoked" prosciutto. My understanding is that prosciutto is un-smoked, cured pork. I'm kind of a dare-devli, but even I'd take that back to where it came from.

Comment: smoked pruss is Speck same thing but smoked regular pruss is cured salted and hung to dry

Answer (score 3):

It looks like lard to me. The cut side of a ham is covered with lard to prevent drying out when curing, often mixed with spices. I wouldn't worry about it. Smoked cured ham is called *speck* in Italian, and mainly produced in the north, notably in Alto Adige.
[image]

Comment: I don't answer because I agree with this. Don't worry. That is typical of speck and smoked prosciutto. Just clean it according to your taste